# Custom expression handler is not being called

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to implement custom expression handler, for debugging purpose i have copy pasted the code from DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler to my custom handler. How ever none of the methods are invoked. Can someone please help me, i am struggling this from past 4 hrs

Below is the configuration

```
 <beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="com.converse.mizu.service.security.acl.CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
  <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator" />
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.AclPermissionEvaluator" id="permissionEvaluator">
  <beans:constructor-arg ref="aclService"/>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService" id="aclService">
  <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="lookupStrategy"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="aclCache"/>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="lookupStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="aclCache"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="aclAuthorizationStrategy"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="auditLogger"/>
    </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="aclCache" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.EhCacheBasedAclCache">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
                <beans:property name="cacheManager">
                    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"/>
                </beans:property>
                <beans:property name="cacheName" value="aclCache"/>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="aclAuthorizationStrategy" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                    <beans:constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                    <beans:constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl">
                    <beans:constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="auditLogger" class="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.ConsoleAuditLogger"/>
```

Basically i would like to apply a post filter on my collection, my secured bean bean looks like this

```
@GET
    @Path("")
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read')")
    public ResponseVO getCampaignsForLoggedInUserByFilter(@QueryParam("sortby") String sortBy, @QueryParam("isDesc") boolean isDescOrder,@QueryParam("start") int start, 
            @QueryParam("limit") int limit,@QueryParam("name") String name) throws MizuException {

        try {
            String userId = SecurityUtil.getCurrentUserId();
            logger.debug("userId = "+userId);

            CampaignList campaignReturnList = getCampaignList(userId, name, limit, sortBy, isDescOrder,  start);
            ResponseVO responseVO = GenericUtil.constructResponseVO(ServiceConstants.SUCCESS, null, campaignReturnList);

            return responseVO;
        } catch (MizuException mze) {
            throw mze;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new MizuException(ErrorConstants.CAMPAIGN_SERVICE_FAILED);
        }
    }



//@PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'read')")
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public CampaignList getCampaignList(String userId,String name,int limit,String sortBy,boolean isDescOrder, int start) throws MizuException{
 ..logic to get the data from DB
}
```

When i apply the post filter annotation on getCampaignsForLoggedInUserByFilter method, at least my custom expressionhandler is being called and get an error "Filter target must be a collection or array type, but was"- which is expected, but if i have the annotation on getCampaignList which actually returns my collection, no error is shown and all my collection is being retuned, custom expressionHandler is not being called. I am assuming that the annotation should work anywhere in the code and need not be the entry point of invocation.

Below is my security configuration. Please note that below configuration is there from long time, the only change is the inclusion of the acl-context file.

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" authentication-manager-ref="mizuAuthenticationManager" >
        <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
    </global-method-security>

<http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />  
    <http pattern="/img/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/font/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/index.html*" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/rest/url/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/rest/user/resetpwd/**" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/rest/uiads/analytics/uispec/**" security="none" />

    <http entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint" pattern="/autologin">
        <custom-filter ref="preAuthFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <session-management invalid-session-url="/" >
            <concurrency-control session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" />
        </session-management>
    </http>

    <http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="mizuAuthenticationEntryPoint"   disable-url-rewriting="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/signup/selfserve/register/account**"  access="hasRole('CREATE_ACCOUNT')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/html/admin/studio.htm"  access="hasRole('SYS_ADMIN_USER')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/html/register_company.html"  access="hasRole('CREATE_ACCOUNT')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/html/adStudio.htm**"  access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/html/adcreator.htm**"  access="isAuthenticated() and hasRole('AD_CREATOR_TOOL')"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/signup/**"  access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**"  access="isAuthenticated()"/>

        <custom-filter ref="mizuAuthenticationProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
        <custom-filter ref="rememberMeFilter" position="REMEMBER_ME_FILTER"/>
        <custom-filter ref="concurrencyFilter" position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER"/>
        <custom-filter ref="requestValidationFilter" before="LAST"/>
        <custom-filter ref="customLogoutFilter" position="LOGOUT_FILTER"/>

        <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>

        <!-- <logout invalidate-session="true" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/> -->
        <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>

    </http>
```

Comment: You should explain what you are doing that makes you expect them to be invoked - where are the secured beans declared, what annotations have you used and what tests have you written to invoke them? What do you see in the log when you run them?

Comment: basically i would like to apply post filter to my domain collection and i have updated my changes in the original post. Thanks

Comment: Found the root cause of the issue, its explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352562/spring-security-and-postfilter